Do Japanese schools not have janitors?
I heard it claimed that Japanese schools do not have janitors, so as to teach the students the discipline to clean up after themselves. Is this true?

Where did you hear?

This site is still about the Japanese language, not about Japan or about being Japanese. There's a culture tag for questions about how culture is reflected in language. It's not for asking generally about what the culture is.

@JimmyYang From someone married to a Japanese woman.

@KarlKnechtel Is there another StackExchange site better suited for my question?

I feel like r/Japan or r/AskAJapanese (reddit) would be a better place to ask than anything I can think of on stack exchange.

@Leebo Thanks. I've asked on r/AskAJapanese.
